Add languages flag for change lang in Bootsrap navbar
I'm stuck with this dilemma. I have a navbar (of which I'm attaching HTML and CSS code) to which I would like to add, on the far right, near the edge, two icons of two flags: an Italian one and an English one. These flags should be clickable and would call a JavaScript function.
Initially, this language change operation was done in the footer of the website with this code here:
<section style="background-color: #000;color: #fff; text-align: justify; font-size: 0.8em;">
    <div class="pt-2 pb-2">
      <p data-i18n="lang_p_1" style="display:inline"></p>
      <a href="#header" onclick="changeLanguage('en')" data-i18n="lang_a_1" style="display:inline ;color:#fff"
        class="bold"></a>
      -
      <a href="#header" onclick="changeLanguage('ita')" data-i18n="lang_a_2" style="display:inline ;color:#fff"
        class="bold"></a>
    </div>
  </section>

However, it's not very user-friendly.
I should mention that it might seem strange, but all the texts are not directly present for language management. That is, every element that needs to contain text has a unique "data-i18n" tag that is used to retrieve the text value from a JSON file. In practice, I have two JSON files, one in English and one in Italian, and depending on the selected language, the function retrieves the text to be inserted into that field using the unique "data-i18n" tag.
Here the navbar code:
  <section>
    <nav class="nav bg-body-tertiary bottom-nav" id="main_navbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"
            data-i18n="vision_1">
            &nbsp;
            <img src="./img/freccia_giu.png" alt="Frecce" height="15" class="arrow-icon" id="1_dropdown" />
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#overview" data-i18n="vision_2"></a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#renaturalization" data-i18n="vision_3"></a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#public" data-i18n="vision_4"></a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#employer" data-i18n="vision_5"></a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#economic" data-i18n="vision_6"></a>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#project_plan" role="button" data-i18n="project_plan_1"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#contacts" role="button" data-i18n="contacts"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>

And here the css part:
.nav {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    z-index: 9999;
    text-align: center;
    /*Needed because FAQs section instead will be overlapped with navbar*/
    padding-left: 10vw;
}

.top-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

.bottom-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 51vw;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
    display: flex;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 250px;
}

.nav-link {
    font-family: 'next-tt-bold' !important;
    font-size: 1.15em;
}

.additional_top_padding {
    padding-top: 110px;
}


.navbar-nav .dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: none;
}

.arrow-icon {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

#main_navbar ul li:before {
    content: '\203A';
    margin: 0 0.3em;
    font-family: 'next-tt-regu' !important;
    color: #ffffff00;
    font-size: 5em;
    float: left;
}

#main_navbar ul li {
    line-height: 3em;
    font-family: 'next-tt-bold' !important;
}


.m-00-main-navigation-available .m-00-header-lined-crest:before {
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e4e4;
    font-size: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    right: 0;
    left: 2px;
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
}

Thanks a lot in advance <3
I tried to add this part into the nav bar:
<ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" onclick="changeLang('ita')">
          <img src="./img/ita_flag.png" alt="Ita" width="25" height="15" id="ita_flag">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" onclick="changeLang('en')">
          <img src="./img/en_flag.png" alt="Eng" width="25" height="15" id="en_flag">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

but nothing. Also reading this existing topic Language picker in the navbar right side with Bootstrap

"but nothing" is really not much of a useful problem description. Have you first of all checked the console for JS errors? Have you debugged a bit, to see if the changeLang function actually gets invoked when you click those links? (And why is the dropdown-toggle class on elements, that do not have the purpose of toggling any dropdowns?)

Bootstrap v4 and Bootstrap v5 have a lot of significant differences between them, so tagging this with both versions, makes rather little sense. Please tag with the appropriate version only.

@CBroe I'm using Bootstrap 5.3.0 alpha and "but nothing" means that i don't have any error in console but does not appear as i would

Then you need to debug the JavaScript portion of this. Like I said, I'd start by checking if a click actually invokes the function - or if maybe event handlers added by Bootstrap have prevented that from happening to begin with. (As mentioned, the dropdown-toggle class seems quite out of place on those element, but I can't say if BS might already interfere based on that alone.)
